# Compare getValue with map.layers[i].name

Tags: extjs, openlayers, extjs3, geoext

As part of a xtype combo, I would like to know if the layer I choose in my simple data store (represented by `this.getValue()`) is present in the map layers. So if it does, `A` should occur, and `B` if it does not. The problem is that `myLayer` variable seems to be unrecognized, even though Opera Dragonify throws no error at all. Where would be the error?

```
listeners: {
  'select': function(combo, record) {
    for(var i = 0; i < mapPanel.map.length; i++) {
      var myLayer = mapPanel.map.layers[i].name;
      if (myLayer == this.getValue()) {
        // do A here...
      } else {
        // do B here...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any pointers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Guilherme Lopes Thanks for that, but the solution was this: `mapPanel.map.layers.length` instead of `mapPanel.map.length`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using `this.getValue()` instead of using `combo.getValue()`.
I don't know how your app is set but it's usually a better idea to use the first parameter of your listener instead of the keywork `this` in order to avoid scope issues.

Hope this helps